# Microsoft Interops Word Insert Comment into Table Cell Crash Word

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, interopservices

i want open a word document programmatically using Microsoft.Interop.Word and insert a comment into a table cell.
I have the start and End position of Range of the cell. (Range.Start \ Range.End)

```
Application.ActiveDocument.Select(); // select ative document
Range rg = Application.Selection.Range; // get the range of the current selection (all document)


 if (rg.Tables.Count > 0)
 {

     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rngTab = rg;

     //set the coordinate of the Range of the text 
     rngTab.Start = startRng;
     rngTab.End = endRng;


     doc.ActiveWindow.Visible = true;
     rg.Select();
     Application.ActiveDocument.Comments.Add(rngTab, ref commentText);                                           
  }
```

When insert comment Word Crashes

Comment: Word crashes? without a error message? Is Word installed correctly? wich version of Word? Please add the answers to your question!

Comment: Microsoft Word 2013, Word installed correctly and no error message, no exception, simply crash "Microsoft Word has stopped working" then restart microsoft word. If i insert the comment  at plane text it works well

Comment: Interops Versione 14.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I convert your code to **pascal** with some changes. **It work fine,** without error!
 *See it*

```
var WApplication:twordapplication; rg,rngTab:range;
commentText:olevariant;
begin
commentText:='123';
WApplication := twordapplication.Create(form1);
WApplication.Connect;
WApplication.Visible:=true;
WApplication.Activate;
rg:= WApplication.Selection.Range; // get the range of the current selection (all document)
rngTab:= rg;
     //set the coordinate of the Range of the text
     rngTab.Start:= 1;
     rngTab.End_:= 2;
     rg.Select();
     WApplication.ActiveDocument.Comments.Add(rngTab, commentText);// add comment to text
     rngtab:=WApplication.ActiveDocument.Tables.Item(1).cell(2,2).range;
     rngtab.Select();
     WApplication.ActiveDocument.Comments.Add(rngTab, commentText); // add comment to cell in the table
end;
```